# assign non-static const member in class with const_cast

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, const-cast

Why can a non-static const member be assigned using const_cast, and when would this be useful?

In the following code, both A and B classes compile and work fine.  However, for B, its const member s is not initialized using an initializer list in the constructor, but by removing the const with const_cast and passing it a value by reference. It can also be written as *(string&)s = _s;*

I don't often see a const_cast on the left side of an assignment, but this one seems to work fine.  What are the pros and cons of B's constructor?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(const string& _s) : s(_s) {}
    void display() {cout << s << endl;}
private:
    const string s;
};

class B {
public:
    B(const string& _s) {
        const_cast<string&>(s) = _s;
    }
    void display() {cout << s << endl;}
private:
    const string s;
};

int main() {
    A a("abc");
    a.display();
    B b("def");
    b.display();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
def
```

Comment: The "cons" of `B::B` is that is has an unnecessary `const_cast`. It has nothing in its "pros" list.

Comment: Using `const_cast` to assign to a `const` object is UB.

Comment: _Why can (bad thing) be done in C++?_  Because C++ is not a nanny language, and provides you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  When the programmer uses a cast, they're telling the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing" and the compiler trusts them even if they don't know what they're doing.

Comment: Only use `const_cast` if you know for sure that the object the `const` reference is referencing is not declared `const`. Otherwise you will cause undefined behavior sooner or later when trying to modify a `const` object. And even for these cases, there are usually alternatives that don't require the cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can a non-static const member be assigned using const_cast, and when would this be useful?

Depends on what you mean by "can".

The program is well-formed because you modify a non-const lvalue.

The behaviour of the program is undefined because you modify a const object.

> and when would this be useful?

Modifying a const object can never be useful.

Casting away const from a reference is sometimes, although rarely, useful which is why const_cast exists. But it is only useful when you have a const reference to a non-const object.

> What are the pros ... of B's constructor?

None.

> What are the ... cons of B's constructor?

The behaviour of the program is undefined if B's constructor is called.

Comment: Thank you.  Does the answer also hold if instead of `const_cast<string&>(s) = _s;` I write `(string&) s = _s;`?  I believe that the 2nd variant is in reality converted to the 1st one by the compiler.

Comment: Yes. That is equivalent. Avoid using the latter in all cases. Only cast away constness with const cast.